# persist many-to-many relationship with EJB

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I'm using JPA (hibernate), EJB and CDI bean (JSF). I have two tables: technology (entity is Technology.class) and component (entity is Component.class) with many-to-many relationship.
Entity code:

```
public class Technology implements Serializable{
...
@Lob
@Column(nullable=false)
private String title;
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="technologies")
private List<Component> components;
..
}

public class Component implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="technology_has_component"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="component_title", nullable=false)
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="technology_tId", nullable=false)
            }
        )
    private List<Technology> technologies;
...
}
```

Code in EJB:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public void addTech(Technology tech) throws Exception {     
    em.persist(tech);
}
```

My JSF page uses CDI bean with properties and method:

```
    @Named(value = "adminActionTech")
    @SessionScoped
    public class AdminActionTech implements Serializable{
    ...

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String addTech() {
        Technology tech = new Technology();
        tech.setTitle(title);
            ...

        tech.setComponents(getListAvaiComps());
        try {
             techService.addTech(tech); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private List<Component> getListAvaiComps() {
          List<Component> listNewComponent = new ArrayList<Component>();
          Component findComp = compService.findComp(component.getTitle()); // findComp() is a method in a EJB
          listNewComponent.add(findComp);
          return listNewComponent;
    }
```

When i add a new technology with title,....,list components. everything is good except list components is not added. i checked technology table, a new record is created, but technology_has_component table has not more record added.
I debug, and be sure, getListAvailComps method is not null.
Can you show me how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`@CascadeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) on the relationship to something including `PERSIST` if you want new objects persisted when their container is.

Comment: So sorry, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in a couple of entities

In Technology.java

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "technologiescomponents")
private Set<Component> components;
```

in Component.java

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "components")
private Set<Technology> technologys;
```

and for the database

```
CREATE TABLE technologiescomponents
(
  component_id bigint NOT NULL,
  product_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: the @JoinTable should be on the owning side of the relationship